# Azure Storage Account Soft Delete with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

Hi,

Can anyone explain the difference between `Enable-AzStorageDeleteRetentionPolicy` and `Enable-AzStorageBlobDeleteRetentionPolicy`?

I am working on a PowerShell script to automate creation of storage accounts amongst other processes. During my research, I realized that these two options exist. However, the difference is not clear from the Microsoft documentation. Both have the description **"... enables delete retention policy for the Azure Storage Blob service**."**

For the first cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/enable-azstoragedeleteretentionpolicy?view=azps-6.2.0

For the second cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/enable-azstorageblobdeleteretentionpolicy?view=azps-6.2.0

Answer (score 3):

Great question! Based on the documentation and examples [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-blob-enable?tabs=azure-powershell), while both Cmdlets do the same thing (i.e. manage blob soft-delete settings) there is one subtle difference:

`Enable-AzStorageDeleteRetentionPolicy` is used for storage accounts with hierarchical namespaces enabled (i.e. your Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Storage accounts) while `Enable-AzStorageBlobDeleteRetentionPolicy` is for your regular storage accounts where hierarchical namespace is not enabled.